# How to use INPUT_HARDWARE on SendInput to simulate an XBox controller input?

Tags: c++, windows, input

So far I've been capable of using [SendInput(](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx)) function to simulate mouse and keyboard virtual keys and scan keys using `MOUSEINPUT` and `KEYBDINPUT`.

I read (on S.O) that `INPUT_HARDWARE` [is for other devices rather than the mouse or keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14547797/1513286). I'm trying to simulate an Xbox controller (or any controller, if that might help) input using `SendInput()`  and the [HARDWAREINPUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646269.aspx) structure. Is it possible to do so? How to do it properly?

Comment: It seems there is an answer on SO already, [have a look](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28687064/147805)

Answer (score 0):

According to the leaked WinXP source code `INPUT_HARDWARE` event type is not supported at all by [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) on a system level after Win98:

```cpp
case INPUT_HARDWARE:
            if (fCanDiscontinue) {
                /*
                 * Not supported on NT.
                 */
                RIPERR0(ERROR_CALL_NOT_IMPLEMENTED, RIP_WARNING, "xxxSendInput: INPUT_HARDWARE is for 9x only.");
                goto discontinue;
            }
            break;
```

According to Wine source code it seems it was used in some old code for HID device support.

> I trying to simulate an Xbox controller (or any controller, if that might help) input using SendInput() and the HARDWAREINPUT structure.

Better try to use [Virtual Gamepad Emulation Framework](https://vigem.org/) (ViGEmBus) for this. It can emulate XInput controllers and is battle tested.